# LonglistSelector in scrollViewer not scrollable

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, longlistselector, windows-phone-toolkit

In my project, I need to show a list of buttons with choices in custommessagebox.

Now, I have no problem in setting it up, but when I create the longlistselector, add it to scrollviewer and show the cusstommessagebox, only a few buttons are shown and i can't scroll for more.

The code I have is following:

```
    private void btnChronicity_ButtonClicked(object sender, Events.LinkEventArgs e)
    {
        editBox = new CustomMessageBox() 
        {
           ....
        };

        ScrollViewer viewer = new ScrollViewer();
        choiceSelector = new Controls.MessageBocChoiceSelectorControl();
        List<items> chronicity = new List<items>();
        foreach (ChronicityModel chronicity in ...Chronicities)
        {
            chronicity.Add(new items(chronicity.Name, chronicity.Selected, chronicity.Id));
        }

        choiceSelector.ItemSource = chronicity;
        editBox.Content = viewer;
        editBox.Show();
    }
```

and the choiceselector is usercontrol, which looks like:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Controls:LongListSelector x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Controls:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Controls1:CheckableListButton Header1="{Binding Header}"
                                           Selected="{Binding Selected}"
                                           Link="{Binding Link}"
                                           ButtonClicked="CheckableListButton_ButtonClicked"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Controls:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
    </Controls:LongListSelector>
</StackPanel>
```

where `listbutton` is another control, basically `button` containing several `textBlocks`, boolean indicating whether it is selected (another style) or not and a string `Link`, which is returned in custom click event.

The result looks this way:
[image: Problem]

But the problem is I can't scroll...

**Why is it behaving like that? How to fix it?**

### EDIT:

As I play with the longlistselector and stuff around I have found out that the scrolling works, the problem is the LongListSelector only loads as much items as fits the messagebox instead all of them..... (when i create smaller messagebox, it shows less items, when i create bigger, it shows more)

So the question shifted a bit to:

**HOW TO MAKE LONGLISTSELECTOR SHOW ALL OF THE ITEMS INSTEAD OF JUST AS MUCH AS FITS THE SCREEN.**

Comment: You doesn't seem to be fixing the height of scrollviewer. Try to give some Height to ScrollViewer, so that scrolls when its childs height is more than its height

Comment: you can not make longlistselector in scrollviewer

Comment: where is solution on that page?

Comment: I don't mean that there is a solution on that page, I just mean that he is using longlistselector in scrollviewer and it works, so I don't see why u're telling it's not possible when it clearly is.

Answer (score 3):

So there are three distinct problems I see with the code:

1. You are creating a new instance of the ScrollViewer in C#, but you are not actually adding the `choiceSelector` instance to the `viewer` instance. Not sure if you just left that out in your sample, or you are not actually adding it.
2. I would not recommend adding a LongListSelector in a ScrollViewer.... because it already scrolls by default. Your problem is that you're putting the LongListSelector in a StackPanel, which will not constrain the height of the LongListSelector in any way.

   Instead I would put the LongListSelector in a Grid control, with the
   row height defined as *. This will mean that the Grid height is
   constrained to the parent container.
3. Having said that, have you looked into the ListPicker control from the http://phone.codeplex.com Toolkit? That seems like it is a little closer to what you are looking for.

HTH

Comment: 1. Yep, it's just left out of the sample. I'll  fix it.

2. I don't know, it usually does not then I'm using it. Is there some property I should set so it would?

3. Didn't knwo about listpicker, I'll look into it in my spare time :)

Comment: 2. - Read about it, but never encountered it. Even though I changed the stackpanel for grid (with rowdefinition set to * and longlistselector specifically se to that row), it does not work.

Comment: Perfect. I had a LongListSelector in a StackPanel and it lost its ability to scroll for the reasons given above. Changed to a Grid and it's good now.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I used longlistselector in my code and it works perfectly for me with infinite scrolling.
See if it helps you.

```
<Grid Background="#FFE6E2E2" Margin="10,10,0,0">
 <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="lb" Margin="0,0,0,0" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"></phone:LongListSelector>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you please try it inside CustomMessageBox (part of Windows Phone Toolkit)? Because the solution I have works on regular page, but not inside CustomMessageBox - plus the textWrapping on it stopped working too even though I have maximum width set....

Answer (score 0):

Restrict the height of the longlistselector to some 200 or so, which is less than the height of the usercontrol. Make sure you mention the Height = " " property in the xaml of the longlist selector.